# Android: Get listview value from an "2-line" listview on onclick

Tags: android, listview

when i click on a listview with a two_line_list_item. I want to get the value from the first line.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
          item = new HashMap<String,String>();
          item.put( "line1", "my_line");
          item.put( "line2", "my_sub");
          list.add( item );

        sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item ,new String[] { "line1","line2" }, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    setListAdapter( sa );

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            String test = lv.getItemAtPosition(position)
        }
    });
```

String test wil contain:"{line1=my_line,line2=my_sub}"

How can i output only the value "my_line"

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] strings = { "line1","line2" };
    sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item , strings, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    setListAdapter( sa );
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            String test = strings[position];
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did edit my code. since i use a hashmap i cant use your array method. But shouldn't it be possible to take the value from the listview and not from the collection that will fill it?

Comment: onItemClick(){String test = v.getText().toString();}?

Comment: v does not has getText() property.